# java generic cast question

Tags: java, generics, casting

I want to implement a sort of transfer object pattern. So, i have a method that fills object´s properties via BeanUtils.copyProperties(..,..) (apache common).

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class BaseTO<TObject> {

    public Long id;

    /***
     * Obtains id of the object that´s transfered
     * @return object´s id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /****
     * set transfered object´s id 
     * @param id object´s id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /***
     * Fill transfer object properties.
     * @param entity entity to be transfered
     * @return self reference
     */
    public BaseTO<TObject> build(TObject entity){
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, entity);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        customDataTransformation(entity);
        return this;
    }

    protected void customDataTransformation(TObject entity) {
    }


}
```

CustomerTO Class

```
public class CustomerTO extends BaseTO<Customer> {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private String sex;
    private DocumentType documentType;
    private String documentNumber;

    --- getters and setters

    @Override
    protected void customDataTransformation(Customer entity) {
        this.sex = Sex.MALE.equals(entity.getSex()) ? "M" : "F";
    }


}
```

the problem

```
CustomerTO toEdit = (CustomerTO) (customerId!=null ? new CustomerTO().build(entityObject):new CustomerTO());
```

as you can see here have to cast to (CustomerTO). I want if it´s possible avoid that, to make the code simpler.

Is it posible that *public BaseTO build(TObject entity)* can return the object of the subclass??

I hope to be clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you write all this just because you want to skip 1 little cast?

Comment: @toto: I think that the question is more than about just casting but is also about compile-time type checking. +1 to the question.

Comment: @toto. No, i will used in a lot of places.

Comment: I'm not an expert on [this pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transfer_Object) but I don't think this is how it's intended to be used. It's for tranfering data, not ease of inheritance.  It looks like you want an object factory that stores properties for all possible objects and spits out subclasses on demand, with the type determined at runtime. What's wrong with the good ol' copy constructor?  `CustomerTO toEdit = new CustomerTO(entityObject)` You'll get compile-time checking and a much simpler codebase to maintain. I think you're trying to be too clever.

Comment: @Paul i´m trying to separete business logic from presentation. I will change the code using constructors. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
    class BaseTO<TObject, R extends BaseTO<TObject,R>> {

    public R build(TObject entity) {
```

and then CustomerTO:

```
class CustomerTO extends BaseTO<Customer, CustomerTO> {
```

or less restrictively, only change the `build` signature:

```
public <X extends BaseTO<TObject>> X build(TObject entity) {
```

But IMHO better approach will be simply adding constructor to TO with TObject parameter.

```
public BaseTO(TObject entity) {
        try {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, entity);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        customDataTransformation(entity);
}
```

then in each extending class create simple constructor

```
     public CustomerTO(Customer entity) {
        super(entity);
    }
```

and forget about the `build` method and use it simply

```
CustomerTO toEdit = (customerId!=null ? new CustomerTO(entityObject):new CustomerTO());
```

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
public class BaseTO<T> {

    public BaseTO<T> build(T entity) {
       return this;
    }

    public static class CustomerTO extends BaseTO<String> {

       @Override public CustomerTO build(String string) {
           return (CustomerTO) super.build(string);
       }
}
```

but you will have to override `build` for all subclasses of `BaseTO`.  You write explicitly the cast only once instead of every time you call `build`.

**EDIT**: see the point raised by @Paul in the comments above.  You might be suffering from "give a man a hammer and everything looks like a nail to him."